# How to target elements of a SimpleModal popup post

Tags: jquery, resize, simplemodal

I'm using the [simplemodal plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) along with this [tutorial](http://wordpressthemescollection.com/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery-488.html) to popup posts on my wordpress site from thumbs on the homepage. I've read through the tutorials over and over and can't figure out how to target the overlay to style it. I also need to target the simplemodal-container aswell to style that. The tutorial gives this function to call a popup post.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.postpopup').click(function(){
        id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://urlofyoursite.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The simplemodal plugin says you can change the style of the overlay by using `overlayCss [Object:{}]` and change the style of the simplemodal-container using `containerCss [Object:{}]`. However, anywhere I try to place that in this function causes issues. I tried adding this under the function above, but it doesn't do anything.

```
jQuery("#ajax-popup").modal({
    opacity:80,
    overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"},
    containerCss: {margin: "0 auto",top:0}
});
```

What am I doing wrong and where I do I need to add this?

Update: Ok Im getting somewhere but the container css won't override the default setting for some reason.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://fameordie.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
           opacity:90,
           containerCss:{
               top:0
           },
           overlayClose:true
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://fameordie.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
           opacity:90,
           position: ["0%"],
           overlayClose:true
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
.modalWrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That's already applied. It applies those setting to browser size on page load but doesn't auto resize.

Comment: make sure that the wrapper can handle it, and the wrapper has to be display:block; as well, and position:relative or absolute;

Comment: The wrapper has that css. The outer container is fixed position to keep the popup in view while scrolling. So I think I need autoresize added with jquery but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: After you add the element you can access it with `jquery("#obj").css({'height': measuredHeight});` and do so for each property you need to effect.